# spark's DataGrid calculateDropIndex equivalent

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

Is there any function (or any easy way to implement it) equivalent to calculateDropIndex for spark's DataGrid?

(using Flex Hero 4.5.0.19786)

Thanks

Comment: A function (provided by mx:AdvancedDataGrid -and mx:DataGrid afaik) that gives you the position of the item the mouse is over in the DataGrid when dragging something (therefore, it is not necessarily the same as the selected item).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so because drag&drop won't be supported for DataGrid in the 4.5 Release